# Duplicating JQuery/Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery/javascript function that creates an array to be placed in a form's hidden field. However, this is a nested form and so I need to invoke this function many times to populate the hidden field for all the children: `test_suite_run[test_runs_attributes][//id][packages_id]`. This means that I need to run this function with a different child id each time.

I have added `//id` to indicate the only differences between the many function calls. I do not know how to duplicate this function without copying it many times manually and replacing //id with the indexes 0...n, for each nested child instance. Could this somehow be done by passing parameters to the javascript function?

Sorry if this a little confusing, I will be happy to explain in more detail if needed.

JQuery Function

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    arr = new Array();

    $(document).on('change', 'select[id ^="s_package//id"]', function () {
        var arr = $('select[id ^="s_package//id"]').map(function () {
            return this.value
        })

        result = ""

        for (j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
            result += (arr[j] + ", ");
        }

        result += (arr[arr.length - 1])


        $("input[name='test_suite_run[test_runs_attributes][//id][packages_id]']").val(result);

    });
});
```

Comment: Instead is using the selector based on id. I would say use the selector as class as the on() function that you are using will automatically bind the change event and the function to the all the elements created in the future with that class so that you dont have to repeat this function again. http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ $(document).on('change', '.some_class', function ()

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array of ids to use in your function and iterate them:

```
function somethingMeaningful(ids) {
    for (var i = 0, l = ids.length; i < l; i++) {
        var id = ids[i];
        // do something with this id
    }
}

$(function() {
    somethingMeaningful(['id1', 'id2', 'idn']);
});
```

It might also be possible to simplify your selector and calculate the id at runtime, depending on their actual format:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[id^="s_package"]', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').slice('s_package'.length);
    // Do stuff with real id
});
```